# Class not registered when calling my Delphi COM object from a WPF project in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, delphi, pascal

I get the following error when I try to call my Delphi COM object from my 32-bit WPF .NET project in Visual Studio 2019 (`var x = new DelphiCOMServiceImplementation();`):

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {D448873F-EAF7-4F40-8BC7-EF9853E64A0F} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

On the 32-bit Delphi ActiveX project side (I am running Delphi 10.3), my COM interface looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The TLB's Pascal interface is generated as follows:

```
interface

uses Winapi.Windows, System.Classes, System.Variants, System.Win.StdVCL, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.OleServer, Winapi.ActiveX;


// *********************************************************************//
// GUIDS declared in the TypeLibrary. Following prefixes are used:
//   Type Libraries     : LIBID_xxxx
//   CoClasses          : CLASS_xxxx
//   DISPInterfaces     : DIID_xxxx
//   Non-DISP interfaces: IID_xxxx
// *********************************************************************//
const
  // TypeLibrary Major and minor versions
  DelphiCOMServiceMajorVersion = 1;
  DelphiCOMServiceMinorVersion = 0;

  LIBID_DelphiCOMService: TGUID = '{E999851C-1E08-4C64-B82A-C3A979F96C2F}';

  IID_IDelphiCOMService: TGUID = '{D91553DB-A372-4279-AD31-9A1AE0C68F23}';
  CLASS_DelphiCOMServiceImplementation: TGUID = '{D448873F-EAF7-4F40-8BC7-EF9853E64A0F}';
type

// *********************************************************************//
// Forward declaration of types defined in TypeLibrary
// *********************************************************************//
  IDelphiCOMService = interface;
  IDelphiCOMServiceDisp = dispinterface;

// *********************************************************************//
// Declaration of CoClasses defined in Type Library
// (NOTE: Here we map each CoClass to its Default Interface)
// *********************************************************************//
  DelphiCOMServiceImplementation = IDelphiCOMService;


// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: IDelphiCOMService
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {D91553DB-A372-4279-AD31-9A1AE0C68F23}
// *********************************************************************//
  IDelphiCOMService = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{D91553DB-A372-4279-AD31-9A1AE0C68F23}']
    procedure EmbedWPFWindow(Pointer: LongWord; Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
    procedure WindowResized(Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  IDelphiCOMServiceDisp
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {D91553DB-A372-4279-AD31-9A1AE0C68F23}
// *********************************************************************//
  IDelphiCOMServiceDisp = dispinterface
    ['{D91553DB-A372-4279-AD31-9A1AE0C68F23}']
    procedure EmbedWPFWindow(Pointer: LongWord; Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); dispid 201;
    procedure WindowResized(Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); dispid 202;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// The Class CoDelphiCOMServiceImplementation provides a Create and CreateRemote method to
// create instances of the default interface IDelphiCOMService exposed by
// the CoClass DelphiCOMServiceImplementation. The functions are intended to be used by
// clients wishing to automate the CoClass objects exposed by the
// server of this typelibrary.
// *********************************************************************//
  CoDelphiCOMServiceImplementation = class
    class function Create: IDelphiCOMService;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): IDelphiCOMService;
  end;

implementation

uses System.Win.ComObj;

class function CoDelphiCOMServiceImplementation.Create: IDelphiCOMService;
begin
  Result := CreateComObject(CLASS_DelphiCOMServiceImplementation) as IDelphiCOMService;
end;

class function CoDelphiCOMServiceImplementation.CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): IDelphiCOMService;
begin
  Result := CreateRemoteComObject(MachineName, CLASS_DelphiCOMServiceImplementation) as IDelphiCOMService;
end;

end.
```

My Delphi CoClass implementation is as follows (this is the class it can't seem to find as registered, so I am wondering if my implementation is correct or if I missed some detail):

```
unit DelphiCOMServiceUnit;

interface

uses ComObj, DelphiCOMService_TLB, Winapi.ActiveX, StdVcl;

type
  DelphiCOMServiceImplementation = class(TAutoObject, IDelphiCOMService)
  public
    procedure EmbedWPFWindow(Pointer: LongWord; Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
    procedure WindowResized(Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
  end;

implementation

procedure DelphiCOMServiceImplementation.EmbedWPFWindow(Pointer: LongWord; Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
begin

end;

procedure DelphiCOMServiceImplementation.WindowResized(Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
begin

end;

end.
```

I have tried both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of `regsvr32` without any issues (it always registers successfully):

`regsvr32 DelphiCOMService.dll`

`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe DelphiCOMService.dll`

I have tried running **dumpbin /exports** on DelphiCOMService.dll, and it looks okay to me:

> Dump of file DelphiCOMService.dll
>
> File Type: DLL
>
> Section contains the following exports for DelphiCOMService.dll
>
> ```
> 00000000 characteristics
>        0 time date stamp
>     0.00 version
>        1 ordinal base
>        8 number of functions
>        8 number of names
>
> ordinal hint RVA      name
>
>       7    0 00101BE0 DllCanUnloadNow
>       8    1 00101B98 DllGetClassObject
>       4    2 00101C90 DllInstall
>       6    3 00101C08 DllRegisterServer
>       5    4 00101C4C DllUnregisterServer
>       3    5 00065514 TMethodImplementationIntercept
>       2    6 00010890 __dbk_fcall_wrapper
>       1    7 00214640 dbkFCallWrapperAddr
> ```
>
> Summary
>
> ```
>     7000 .bss
>     6000 .data
>   997000 .debug
>     1000 .didata
>     1000 .edata
>     4000 .idata
>     2000 .itext
>     1000 .rdata
>    30000 .reloc
>     7000 .rsrc
>   208000 .text
> ```

Could anyone tell me what I can do to get C# to be able to call into my Delphi COM object's function? Did I miss something when I created that unit which houses the DelphiCOMServiceImplementation type, or miss a detail when implementing it, and thus, that causes the CoClass to not be found as a registered object? I tried to find the COM wizards that I keep reading about in my version of Delphi in order to create a class using them and comparing what works to what doesn’t, but I couldn’t find any wizard in my version of Delphi for creating COM classes.

Comment: Sure, but it's surprising how many qs are posted here where the OP doesn't.

Comment: @MartynA I have this suspicion that the way I set up my class implementation for the `CoClass` interface definition is not correct. Meaning, I think the code in my `DelphiCOMServiceUnit` (above) is not correct. I manually coded the `DelphiCOMServiceImplementation` class in that unit. What is linking that class to COM for consumption? Is it enough to just code a new type like I did with the same name as my CoClass's name? Does the unit name matter? Does it have to exist under a certain namespace, etc.?

Comment: @MartynA Is that in `DllRegisterServer`? I never implemented anything like that.

Comment: Probably easiest if you take a look at e.g. http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/master-delphi-7/content/LiB0121.html, which looks like it might be quoting from Marco Cantu's Mastering Delphi 7.

Comment: @MartynA Nice find, my man. Getting closer. I added `initialization TComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, DelphiCOMServiceImplementation, StringToGUID('{D448873F-EAF7-4F40-8BC7-EF9853E64A0F}'), 'DelphiCOMServiceImplementation', '', ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);` to the `DelphiCOMServiceImplementation` class and re-registered it.

Comment: @MartynA Now, I get `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {D448873F-EAF7-4F40-8BC7-EF9853E64A0F} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 8000ffff Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)).'` when running from WPF.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never touched WPF, so I'm out of my depth, but hopefully this will catch an expert's eye.  Might be a good time to tidy up the comments?

Comment: @MartynA Check out the answer I just posted. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, great that you sorted it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this guide](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/master-delphi-7/content/LiB0121.html) and with the help of MartynA, I had a few issues:

Firstly, nothing was registering my `DelphiCOMServiceImplementation` class, even though it had the right name and it implemented the right interface, this class needs to tell COM that it exists. To do this, you add an initialization section:

```
initialization

TComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, DelphiCOMServiceImplementation, StringToGUID('{D448873F-EAF7-4F40-8BC7-EF9853E64A0F}'), 'DelphiCOMServiceImplementation', '', ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
```

Secondly, I believe that the above `TComObjectFactory.Create` function only works on `TComObject` derived types, so I changed the class `DelphiCOMServiceImplementation` inherits as follows (it now derives itself from `TComObject`):

```
DelphiCOMServiceImplementation = class(TComObject, IDelphiCOMService)
```

Thirdly, my interface was originally using `IDispatch` in the *.ridl designer. This was totally over-kill and I suspect I would have needed to do some extra registration steps in order to make it work with this interface (such as reverting back to `TAutoObject` and using `TAutoObjectFactory.Create(…)`, but I don't plan to use automation), so since I don't need it, I switched my interface to `IUnknown` (as shown in the image below) and then did the old *Save All*, *Refresh Implementation*, *Register Type Library*, *Save As Type Library File*, *Build* (right clicking on the solution), *Run -> ActiveX Server -> Register*:

[image]

Now it just works like a charm! My WPF project calls into my functions without any worries. And finally, just to bring things full circle, here is the complete Delphi CoClass implementation:

```
unit DelphiCOMServiceUnit;

interface

uses ComObj, ComServ, DelphiCOMService_TLB, Winapi.ActiveX, StdVcl;

type
  DelphiCOMServiceImplementation = class(TComObject, IDelphiCOMService)
  protected
    procedure EmbedWPFWindow(Pointer: LongWord; Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
    procedure WindowResized(Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
  end;

implementation

procedure DelphiCOMServiceImplementation.EmbedWPFWindow(Pointer: LongWord; Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
begin

end;

procedure DelphiCOMServiceImplementation.WindowResized(Width: SYSINT; Height: SYSINT); safecall;
begin

end;

initialization

TComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, DelphiCOMServiceImplementation, StringToGUID('{D448873F-EAF7-4F40-8BC7-EF9853E64A0F}'), 'DelphiCOMServiceImplementation', '', ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);

end.
```